# How to flag a forum?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, flags, nodes

I'm using advanced forum and flags module to flag forum content. Flagging topics works well - I just turned it on for "Forum topic" content type. But how can I do the same for forums?

Forums are tags, so I added flagging for "Forums" vocabulary and when I visit a forum as a tag (/taxonomy/term/tid) link for flagging is there and that works fine. But when I visit a forum on desired URL  (/forum/forum_id) - link is not there. And there is no forum entity or something which I can use instead of tags.

So, how to set flags module to work with advanced forums and allow users to really flag forums as forums and not as taxonomy terms?

Comment: I guess you should check in the manage display option of the forum

Comment: I don't see display options for forum?!? Also, when I edit some forum at bottom of edit page is "Flags" box, with flag I've created (checkbox), but even if I check that on link for following that forum is not shown.